# Stereoscopic(side by side) mobile web app

Tags: javascript, mobile, web-applications, stereoscopy, google-cardboard

Have little experience with mobile web apps, but want to create an almost stereoscopic image(identical side by side images) of a site (192.168.2.87:8080/jsfs.html). Does anyone know if this is possible with a mobile web app?

In context, it's a video feed using javascript from IP Webcam for Android, and the video is actually rendered in the browser itself by putting together still shots.

Comment: Your biggest problem will be syncing the streams

Comment: Yep, just realized it can be achieved with a simple iFrame, but now syncing the streams is a huge issue